How do I avoid 'TeX capacity exceeded' error, even though I have a small dataset?
I'm trying to make a scatterplot of some measurement data, which is only a <100 datapoints.
So here is my code, hopefully you can help me solve this issue:
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{width=7cm,compat=1.18}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[%
scatter/classes={%
a={mark=o,draw=green}}]
\addplot [
    scatter,
    only marks,
    point meta=explicit symbolic,
    scatter/classes={
        a={mark=o,green},
        b={mark=o,draw=red}% <-- don't add comma
    },
]   table[meta=label] {
x   y   label
0   -0.005  a
0.1 0.069   a
0.3 0.192   a
0.5 0.301   a
0.7 0.414   a
0.9 0.54    a
1.1 0.658   a
1.3 0.767   a
1.5 0.888   a
1.7 1.008   a
1.9 1.125   a
2   1.186   a
1.8 1.063   b
1.6 0.933   b
1.4 0.822   b
1.2 0.697   b
1   0.582   b
0.8 0.461   b
0.6 0.333   b
0.4 0.233   b
0.2 0.12    b
0   -0.007  b
0   0.001   a
0.1 0.077   a
0.3 0.186   a
0.5 0.299   a
0.7 0.418   a
0.9 0.538   a
1.1 0.648   a
1.3 0.769   a
1.5 0.892   a
1.7 1.004   a
1.9 1.12    a
2   1.179   a
1.8 1.07    b
1.6 0.939   b
1.4 0.821   b
1.2 0.702   b
1   0.58    b
0.8 0.457   b
0.6 0.339   b
0.4 0.229   b
0.2 0.124   b
0   -0.009  b
0   -0.004  a
0.1 0.079   a
0.3 0.19    a
0.5 0.302   a
0.7 0.422   a
0.9 0.545   a
1.1 0.657   a
1.3 0.772   a
1.5 0.894   a
1.7 1.007   a
1.9 1.119   a
2   1.185   a
1.8 1.057   b
1.6 0.941   b
1.4 0.819   b
1.2 0.704   b
1   0.576   b
0.8 0.463   b
0.6 0.341   b
0.4 0.235   b
0.2 0.127   b
0   -0.001  b
};
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}

It seems weird to me that this dataset exceeds the memory, so, how can I fix this?

It works if one removes the first scatter/classes={% a={mark=o,draw=green}}. You set it again in the addplot settings, shouldn't this be sufficient?

Oh I must've missed that one... thanks for the correction!

You're welcome!

The code works if one sets the green marker only once:
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{width=7cm,compat=1.18}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[]
\addplot [
    scatter,
    only marks,
    point meta=explicit symbolic,
    scatter/classes={
        a={mark=o,green},
        b={mark=o,draw=red}% <-- don't add comma
    },
]   table[meta=label] {
x   y   label
0   -0.005  a
0.1 0.069   a
0.3 0.192   a
0.5 0.301   a
0.7 0.414   a
0.9 0.54    a
1.1 0.658   a
1.3 0.767   a
1.5 0.888   a
1.7 1.008   a
1.9 1.125   a
2   1.186   a
1.8 1.063   b
1.6 0.933   b
1.4 0.822   b
1.2 0.697   b
1   0.582   b
0.8 0.461   b
0.6 0.333   b
0.4 0.233   b
0.2 0.12    b
0   -0.007  b
0   0.001   a
0.1 0.077   a
0.3 0.186   a
0.5 0.299   a
0.7 0.418   a
0.9 0.538   a
1.1 0.648   a
1.3 0.769   a
1.5 0.892   a
1.7 1.004   a
1.9 1.12    a
2   1.179   a
1.8 1.07    b
1.6 0.939   b
1.4 0.821   b
1.2 0.702   b
1   0.58    b
0.8 0.457   b
0.6 0.339   b
0.4 0.229   b
0.2 0.124   b
0   -0.009  b
0   -0.004  a
0.1 0.079   a
0.3 0.19    a
0.5 0.302   a
0.7 0.422   a
0.9 0.545   a
1.1 0.657   a
1.3 0.772   a
1.5 0.894   a
1.7 1.007   a
1.9 1.119   a
2   1.185   a
1.8 1.057   b
1.6 0.941   b
1.4 0.819   b
1.2 0.704   b
1   0.576   b
0.8 0.463   b
0.6 0.341   b
0.4 0.235   b
0.2 0.127   b
0   -0.001  b
};
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}


